# How to add Twitter card image to post created in blogdown

Tags: twitter, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I created a post in blogdown from a .Rmd file. The header of the file includes:

```
---
title: Social assistance and unemployment duration in Alberta
author: Blake Shaffer
date: '2018-11-30'
slug: caseload-duration
categories: []
tags: []
twitterImg: post/2018-11-29-caseload-duration-files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-5-1.png
header:
  caption: ''
  image: '/caseload-duration-banner.png'
---
```

But when I tweet a link to the post, the image does not appear:

[image: TwitterCard created by link without image]

I am using blogdown via RStudio, and the hugo/gcashen-academic theme.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML that is generated? That will help us find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your post though the Twitter Card Validator - https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

It seems to work - the image is displayed.  Looking through the source for https://www.blakeshaffer.ca/post/caseload-duration/ I notice one possible problem on this line:

`<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://blakeshaffer.ca/post/2018-11-29-caseload-duration_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-5-1.png" >`

You should make sure that the image is referenced using `https` rather than just `http`